# Error app in AWS. 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'

Tags: reactjs, node.js, amazon-web-services, express, jwt

I have a react app saved locally and I want to test it online via AWS. Every time you make changes to an app (in github), AWS redeploys with a different URL. Now my question is, I cant set Origin to be a wildcard "*", since my app involves cookies for login pages and I get the error above. Also, I cannot set Origin to be the current AWS deployed app URL(link) because it will redeploy with a different URL(link) and continue getting the error. In short my deployed app cannot "login"! What should I do? Searched for answers for like 2 days now.

I tried adding CORS blocking extensions but they dint work (CORS work is to secure and if it can be by-passed then we wonder why it is important).

For CORS
In origin, you cant use "*" (cookies security) or AWS link (because it will change upon redeployment)

```
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: ["*"], 
    methods: ["POST", "GET", "PUT", "DELETE"],
    credentials: true,
  })
);
```

Comment: Where are you deploying this app to? AWS is a platform with 250+ services, you need to give more details on where and how your app is deployed. You will likely need to attach your domain to the app so you have a consistent domain you can use in your CORS headers.

Comment: If you could also describe your app in more detail, are you deploying an back-end app to AWS and trying to connect to it from your machine? Or is both the back-end and front-end being deployed to AWS and it needs to talk to itself?

Comment: I am deploying the app to AWS amplify. If I attach the domain (which is temporary apparently) and push the changes to github, the app will redeploy with a different domain so it becomes inconsistent again.